# JOGL - Enabling double buffering increases performance : How?

Tags: opengl, double, jogl, buffering, frame-rate

I am enabling or disabling double buffering using the following code

```
GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);

caps.setDoubleBuffered(false);
```

Now, I was of the understanding that enabling double buffering would reduce performance : reduce the frames per second. Disabling it would improve FPS (of course, with visual artifacts).

But I am getting just the oppposite results. When I enable double buffering I am getting FPS of around 250 (for a model with around 10K triangles). When I disable double buffering, I get around 160 FPS (for the same model).

Can somebody explain this to me? Is it something specific to JOGL or the commands that I have used to enable/disable double buffering?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense. I am interested in this answer too! According to this: http://www.futuretech.blinkenlights.nl/dbuffer.html  it should be the other way around!

Comment: I'd suggest to leave as it is, double buffering is useful. There are many and more suggested way to improve performances